# Where do you sanitize JSON input in your ASP.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have an ASP.net application with a WCF service like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet]
public string DoDeleteRow(GridParameter request)
{ ... do stuff.. }
```

How would you validate the variable "request"?  Do you simply rely on the Microsoft JSON parser and let that reconstruct the object for you, or do you just accept a string input and perform validation prior to processing? something similar to below

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet]
public string DoDeleteRow(string request)
{
   if (CurrentUserIsValid)
   {
     //ASP.net membership
   } 
   if (CanParseObject(request))
   {
      //convert to .NET type
    }
}
```

Where do you place the rest of your input sanitization logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just let the built-in parser do it. I can't imagine what `CanParseObject` would do that didn't simply involve parsing the object and checking for errors...

On the other hand, WCF has a [very extensive customization facility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx), which you can use to validate, parse, inspect, or whatever you like, messages before they're translated into the method calls. So you could build something with that if you wanted.